# What's wrong with my SQL statement?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ado

```
SELECT * FROM [makes$] WHERE "Corporate Name"='Champion Enterprises, Inc.'
```

I'm running this query on an XLS excel file using ADO in VBA.  There are about 10-20 records containing this corporate name but it returns EOF.

I'm fairly new to database but I'm certain everything is correct aside from my SQL statement.

If I `SELECT * FROM [makes$]`, it returns all the records successfully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM [makes$] WHERE [Corporate Name]='Champion Enterprises, Inc.'
```

Answer (score 2):

total guess here but its probably

```
SELECT * FROM [makes$] WHERE [Corporate Name]="Champion Enterprises, Inc."
```

Comment: +1 for the first right answer, but please remove  the total guess part

Answer (score 1):

Use [] instead of "" for column names with spaces in them:

```
SELECT * FROM [makes$] WHERE [Corporate Name]='Champion Enterprises, Inc.'
```